# How to set an object as key in NSMutableDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I need to set an object as key in NSMutableDictionary. I declared my dictionary as

```
var streamsDict : NSMutableDictionary = [:]
```

and adding object as

```
 streamsDict[stream] = "Value"
```

but i am getting following error due to which my application crashes

```
Could not cast value of type 'OTStream' (0x100638590) to 'NSCopying' (0x19e0fb9e8)
```

I also tried

```
streamsDict[stream as! NSCopying] = "Value"
```

but again i am getting errors

```
`Argument type 'OTStream' does not conform to expected type 'NSCopying'`
```

Please suggest

Comment: You can't use just anything as the key in a dictionary, and you don't want to... What are you trying to achieve with the dictionary?

Comment: what is the type of stream variable you are setting as key?

Comment: @Wain: I have OTStream objects and i need to save them in a dictionary with some value. After that i can get array of allKeys of this dictionary to perform my task further.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar: Its an object of OTStream.

Comment: You don't want to do that, explain why you would use the dictionary

Comment: @Wain:I have 2 dictionaries, where in first i am saving my dynamic streams  objects with a value. I am showing these streams on a table view. In my second dictionary i need to save these streams as key and their indexPath as its value.

Comment: Why would you not just have an array of them, or an array of arrays - you should not use a stream as a key...

Comment: @Wain: Thanks!! I am now using multi dimension array (2D array) to achieve my task, but i am stuck how to remove particular array from this multi dimensional array. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Only an object that conforms to `NSCopying` can be used as the key in an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Your `OTStream` object must implement the `NSCopying` protocol if you want to use it as the key in a dictionary.

You can find the `NSCopying` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am getting following error `Argument type 'OTStream' does not conform to expected type 'NSCopying'`

Comment: It is a bad idea to consider making the stream a copy able item

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not store your object directly in dictionary but first serialize all its properties to NSDictionary